# Saving the answers of a survey in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, Survey, Question and Answer, Survey is the main model in which Question is nested to, at the time of creating a new form, I can create and perfectly edit the name of the survey and its questions, however, I have created a view and a method called "take", in which I have the users take the survey, for this I have nested "Answer" inside Question, and Question is nested inside Survey, the answers are visible in reading mode so that do not re-store or update, at the time of saving that form, I need only the "Answers" to be saved, that is, I need a new instance of Answer to be created, and store that answer, however I can not do it despite Add "Answer.new" within the nesting of the form, and I can see that you are not paying attention to the controller, specifically within the Update method, in what way could you keep the questions correctly?

**take.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @survey, local: true) do |form| %>

  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.object.title %>
  </div>

  <div class="fields">
    <%= form.fields_for :questions do |question| %>
      <%= question.object.question_title %> 
      <ol type="a">
        <%= question.fields_for :answers, Answer.new do |answer| %>
          <li><%= answer.text_field :response, placeholder: "Reponse" %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <br> <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**surveys_controller.rb**

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :take, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def take
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @question = @survey.questions.build
  end

  def edit
    @question = @survey.questions.build
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      @answer = Answer.new(id: params[:id], response: params[:response], question_id: params[:question_id])

      if @survey.update(survey_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to surveys_url, notice: 'Survey was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :question_title, :survey_id])
    end
end
```

**models**

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need only the "Answers" to be saved, that is, I need a new instance
>   of Answer to be created, and store that answer, however I can not do
>   it despite Add "Answer.new" within the nesting of the form, and I can
>   see that you are not paying attention to the controller, specifically
>   within the Update method, in what way could you keep the questions
>   correctly?

Well, you are **not saving** the answers in the `update` action! In short, you are missing `@answer.save`

```
@answer = Answer.new(response: params[:response], question_id: params[:question_id])
@answer.save #you are missing this line
```

**Note:**

As you can see I've removed `id: params[:id]` from the `Answer.new` because it could raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` for the duplicate entry.